# Command line execution of C program

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, command-line-arguments

I have a written a C program using Visual Studio 2008. The program compares to files in binary mode and tells us if the files are same or different.

I need to execute this program on command line and need to pass 2 arguments along with it.
the first argument is for the file to be compared and 2nd is the file to which it will be compared.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is he asking how to run the program with arguments or how to read the arguments?

Comment: Is this a question or just a status update? ;) You might want to clarify what your problem is, what you have tried so far and what we can help you with.

Comment: I want to execute the .sln file from command prompt.. how do i pass the arguments?? devenv c:\abc.sln "file1.pdf" "file2.pdf"   does this work??

Comment: i have a solution file filecomp.sln. this program will take the 2 arguements. argv[1] should be file1.pdf and argv[2] should be file2.pdf.. i want to know how on command prompt do i execute the .sln file and pass 2 arguements in command prompt itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int result_code;
    char command_line[256];
    sprintf(command_line, "FC /B %s %s > NUL:", argv[1], argv[2]);
    result_code=system(command_line);
    printf("%s file.\n", result_code ? "different" : "same");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/print/lesson14.html

you can get plenty more from google.